# Query about working out whether number is a power of 2

Tags: algorithm

Using the classic code snippet:

if (x & (x-1)) == 0

If the answer is 1, then it is false and not a power of 2. However, working on 5 (not a power of 2) and 4 results in:

0001 1111
0001 1111
0000 1111

That's 4 1s.

Working on 8 and 7:

1111 1111
0111 1111

0111 1111

The 0 is first, but we have 4.

In this link (http://www.exploringbinary.com/ten-ways-to-check-if-an-integer-is-a-power-of-two-in-c/) for both cases, the answer starts with 0 and there is a variable number of 0s/1s. How does this answer whether the number is a power of 2?

Comment: this is pretty foggy in general, you might think a bit more about your question.

Comment: That's interesting that you didn't know binary... but I suppose it's not necessary if you are "dotnetdev".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need refresh yourself on how binary works. 5 is not represented as 0001 1111 (5 bits on), it's represented as 0000 0101 (2^2 + 2^0), and 4 is likewise not 0000 1111 (4 bits on) but rather 0000 0100 (2^2). The numbers you wrote are actually in *unary*.

[Wikipedia, as usual, has a pretty thorough overview.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_numeral_system)

Comment: Good link. That helps me understand how the solution to this problem works. :)

Answer (score 5):

Any power of two number can be represent in binary with a single 1 and multiple 0s.

```
eg. 
10000(16) 
1000(8) 
100(4)
```

If you subtract 1 from any power of two number, you will get all 1s to the right of where the original one was.

```
10000(16) - 1 = 01111(15)
```

ANDing these two numbers will give you 0 every time.

In the case of a non-power of two number, subtracting one will leave at least one "1" unchanged somewhere in the number like:

```
10010(18) - 1 = 10001(17)
```

ANDing these two  will result in

```
10000(16) != 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that if x is a power of 2, there is *exactly 1 bit set*. Subtract 1, and you know two things: the resulting value is not a power of two, and the bit that was set is no longer set.  So, when you do a *bitwise* and `&`, every bit that was set in `x` is not unset, and all the bits in `(x-1)` that are set must be matched against bits not set in `x`.   So the and of each bit is always 0.

In other words, for any bit pattern, you are guaranteed that `(x&(x-1))` is zero.

Answer (score 1):

((n & (n-1)) == 0)

It checks whether the value of “n” is a power of 2.

Example:

```
 if n = 8, the bit representation is 1000
 n & (n-1) = (1000) & ( 0111) = (0000)
 So it return zero only if its value is in power of 2.
 The only exception to this is ‘0’.
 0 & (0-1) = 0 but ‘0’ is not the power of two.
```

Why does this make sense?

Imagine what happens when you subtract 1 from a string of bits. You read from left to right,
turning each 0 to a 1 until you hit a 1, at which point that bit is flipped:

1000100100 -> (subtract 1) -> 1000100011

Thus, every bit, up through the first 1, is flipped. If there’s exactly one 1 in the number, then every bit (other than the leading zeros) will be flipped. Thus, n & (n-1) == 0 if there’s exactly one 1. If there’s exactly one 1, then it must be a power of two.