# n & (n-1) what does this expression do?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Query about working out whether number is a power of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666647/query-about-working-out-whether-number-is-a-power-of-2)
>   [What does this function do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265942/what-does-this-function-do)

`n & (n-1)` - where can this expression be used ?

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265942/what-does-this-function-do/3265978

Comment: @Paul R, to me it is not a duplicate (albeit related) - this one comes from the other way around, one might say.

Comment: It turns the rightest 1 into 0 of n's binary mode. If the result equals 0, which means there is only one 1 in n's binary mode, which means n is power of 2.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

It's figuring out if `n` is either 0 or an exact power of two.

It works because a binary power of two is of the form `1000...000` and subtracting one will give you `111...111`. Then, when you AND those together, you get zero, such as with:

```
  1000 0000 0000 0000
&  111 1111 1111 1111
  ==== ==== ==== ====
= 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Any non-power-of-two input value (other than zero) will *not* give you zero when you perform that operation.

For example, let's try all the 4-bit combinations:

```
     <----- binary ---->
 n      n    n-1   n&(n-1)
--   ----   ----   -------
 0   0000   0111    0000 *
 1   0001   0000    0000 *
 2   0010   0001    0000 *
 3   0011   0010    0010
 4   0100   0011    0000 *
 5   0101   0100    0100
 6   0110   0101    0100
 7   0111   0110    0110
 8   1000   0111    0000 *
 9   1001   1000    1000
10   1010   1001    1000
11   1011   1010    1010
12   1100   1011    1000
13   1101   1100    1100
14   1110   1101    1100
15   1111   1110    1110
```

You can see that only `0` and the powers of two (`1`, `2`, `4` and `8`) result in a `0000/false` bit pattern, all others are non-zero or `true`.

Comment: How come 7 and -1 both have 0111?

Comment: `n & (n-1)` helps in identifying the value of the last bit. Since the least significant bit  for n and n-1 are either (0 and 1) or (1 and 0) . Refer above table.

`(n & (n-1)) == 0` only checks if n is a power of 2 or 0.

Comment: It's a problem from [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/power-of-two/)

Answer (score 9):

It returns 0 if n is a power of 2 (NB: only works for `n > 0`). So you can test for a power of 2 like this:

```
bool isPowerOfTwo(int n)
{
    return (n > 0) && ((n & (n - 1)) == 0);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It checks if n is a power of 2: [What does the bitwise code "$n & ($n - 1)" do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551500/what-does-the-bitwise-code-n-n-1-do)

Answer (score 1):

It's a bitwise operation between a number and its previous number.  Only way this expression could ever be false is if n is a power of 2, so essentially you're verifying if it isn't a power of 2.