# Evaluate if integer is POT (Power Of Two)

Tags: c, algorithm, bit-manipulation

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Query about working out whether number is a power of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666647/query-about-working-out-whether-number-is-a-power-of-2)
>   [How to check if a number is a power of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600293/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-a-power-of-2)

I require a function body for this prototype:

```
bool isPOT(int x);
```

So it would return eg isPOT(3) = FALSE, but isPOT(8) = TRUE

What is the most pretty/concise algorithm?  And what is the most efficient?

PS: I am amazed that I cannot find this question on SO,  so I am fully expecting someone to detect some duplicate.

PPS:  can someone please create POT, NPOT, Power-Of-Two tags?

Comment: Yes, there are numerous duplicates, e.g. [Query about working out whether number is a power of 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666647/query-about-working-out-whether-number-is-a-power-of-2)

Comment: Why would SO need power-of-two tags ?!

Comment: Strange that I didn't see a match from typing the title, I guess maybe because I used 'two' instead of '2'

Comment: @user470379:  for low-level work / optimisation (especially graphics) POT and NPOT are commonly used acronyms

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
bool IsPOT(int x)
{
    return (x > 0) && ((x & (x - 1)) == 0);
}
```

Comment: One might want to rewrite this in macro form, so that it works on any type of integer #define ISPOW2(x) ( (x)>0 && !( (x) & ((x) - 1) ) )

Comment: @datenwolf: except you then get all the usual problems with macros - it's probably better just to keep as an int function, which will handle char, short and int, and then do an additional version if you need to handle anything wider than an int.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this *exact* question occurred, but the check is easy

```
x & (x - 1) == 0
```

Comment: Almost - you also need to check for x > 0, otherwise you get an incorrect result when `x = 0`.