# Give me a hint about Pyton3 print( if ... else)

Tags: python-3.x

Can you please give me a proper link to read or explain how does this code in Python3 work?

```
print("NO" if (n := int(input())) & (n - 1) else "YES")
```

As far as I understood it checks whether given integer n is equal to some power of 2, but how the hell does it check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluating the code from the outside in, the `print()` call will print out either `"NO"` or `"YES"` based on the [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) (also called ternary operator) `value1 if condition else value2`.

The condition in this case is `(n := int(input())) & (n-1)`. The expression to the left of `&` is called an [assignment expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#assignment-expressions) and is also called the walrus because of how `:=` looks. It assigns the result of `int(input())` to `n` and also uses that value as part of the condition. This way, you can avoid initializing `n` on a separate line (or calling a method again, if it wasn't user input) before re-using it in the right hand side of the condition as `n-1`.

`&` is the [bitwise AND](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations) operation. To see why `(n & (n-1)) == 0` is a valid condition for checking if `n` is a power of 2, take a look at this question: [Query about working out whether number is a power of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666647/query-about-working-out-whether-number-is-a-power-of-2) .

Your conditional expression omits `== 0` because `0` will be [treated as `False`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), and puts the desired output - `"YES"`, for `n` being a power of 2 - in the `else` clause.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the way an integer is stored in binary.
`&` is a [bit-operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations) which is an `AND` gate for the bits left and right of it. And works like this for two bits:

```
1 & 1 => 1
1 & 0 => 0
0 & 1 => 0
0 & 0 => 0
```

Due to the binary representation every power of 2 is represented with a `1` at a position `i` and all zeroes on all positions `< i`. Because of that and the way `AND` works we only get a `1` bit if we have `1` at both positions left and right. So for every power of two we have a single `1` and the rest all zeroes and for every value that is not a power of two will use `<= i-1` bits, at least one of which is different from zero.

The result of the operation `n & (n - 1)`, if we have a power of two `power_of_two & power_of_two - 1`, will always return `0` which is a [`falsy`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39984051/17487348) value in Python so the `else` branch will be triggered. For every value that is not a power of two `not_power_of_two & not_power_of_two - 1` will return something `!= 0` which is a [`truthy`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39984051/17487348) value in Python hence `"NO"` is returned.

Probably this example is easier to understand that all the text above:

| Input | Binary repr. input | Binary repr. input -1 | Result AND (&) binary | Result AND decimal | Python truthy/ falsy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0b0000 | 0b1111 | 0b0000 | 0 | falsy |
| 1 | 0b0001 | 0b0000 | 0b0000 | 0 | falsy |
| 2 | 0b0010 | 0b0001 | 0b0000 | 0 | falsy |
| 3 | 0b0011 | 0b0010 | 0b0010 | 2 | truthy |
| 4 | 0b0100 | 0b0011 | 0b0000 | 0 | falsy |